# Which RPC can get the details of the transaction through the externalics ID?

Tags: rpc

[image]

How can I pass the externalics ID in the picture. Get the details of the deal. Through RPC method.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a need to really use RPC directly?
If so, you can start by:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"id":1, "jsonrpc":"2.0", "method": "chain_getBlockHash", "params": [10463935]}' https://kusama-rpc.polkadot.io
>>>
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":"0x87bf173b7c6edfe811e5e584ce50c9a6056b62c7b87472d8ecb23ae9a706c5e5","id":1}
```

And then:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"id":1, "jsonrpc":"2.0", "method": "chain_getBlock", "params": ["0x87bf173b7c6edfe811e5e584ce50c9a6056b62c7b87472d8ecb23ae9a706c5e5"]}' https://kusama-rpc.polkadot.io
```

Here you will get a bunch of data that you'll have to decode to get what you want.

But you don't have to bother about that and just use `PolkadotJS` or `py-substrate-interface`, eg:

```
from substrateinterface import SubstrateInterface


def get_extrinsic_by_id(substrate, block_number, extrinsic_id):
    result = substrate.get_block(block_number=block_number)
    if result and len(result['extrinsics']) > extrinsic_id:
        return result['extrinsics'][extrinsic_id]
    else:
        print('Extrinsic ID: {extrinsic_id} not found.')

substrate = SubstrateInterface(url="wss://kusama-rpc.polkadot.io")
ext = get_extrinsic_by_id(substrate, block_number=10463935, extrinsic_id=2)

ext:

<GenericExtrinsic(value={'extrinsic_hash': '0x624efb20b7aac1ba4666f9396f5b051443f8e809ab6cc8988c62b977b63bb388', 'extrinsic_length': 147, 'address': 'Cb2QccEAM38pjwmcHHTTuTukUobTHwhakKH4kBo4k8Vur8o', 'signature': {'Ed25519': '0x191a8c70f984732d9fbf7eb18f362a2c179ec8c687dfcda9ae0654390f6c605b259d8597bb3d21efa95c46e0e0970843ed2a238a85c0d64c8bca18efdc144100'}, 'era': (64, 59), 'nonce': 41569, 'tip': 0, 'call': {'call_index': '0x0400', 'call_function': 'transfer', 'call_module': 'Balances', 'call_args': [{'name': 'dest', 'type': 'LookupSource', 'value': 'EaXAkn5ZwmMdnQa8vQx5rU9YZN8XAsACTUTCssGX5XvC22b'}, {'name': 'value', 'type': 'Balance', 'value': 230100000000}], 'call_hash': '0xb58c1473c8556163167d1c4fad6d0811a40d56e50912468a8444e774c7f85d10'}})>
```

Comment: Thank you, but what I want to know is. (get_external_by_id) if this is an RPC, which RPC is it?

Comment: I don't think so... But you can check all the available RPC methods using `curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"id":1, "jsonrpc":"2.0", "method": "rpc_methods"}' https://kusama-rpc.polkadot.io`. And https://polkadot.js.org/docs/substrate/rpc/

Comment: What's your answer? What's the use of all the RPC methods you gave me? What I want is which RPC is used at the bottom? bottom! Do you understand?

Comment: Like I said, I don't think that there is a single RPC method to fetch an extrinsic data. You'll have to fetch the whole block data (`chain_getBlock`) and then decode its content to get what you want. Do you understand?

Comment: I know it needs to be parsed, but you write (get_external_by_id) this is just a method name! What is in this method? This is what I want!

Comment: How did you decode it? Through what classes? What method? How? How to write specifically?

Comment: Sorry but I don't have time to do that work for you. Like I wrote in this comment, you'd be better using some of the available libraries (JS or Python, in my example) to get what you want. I did not write `get_external_by_id` and wrote `get_extrinsic_by_id` and also its content to help you in some directions.

Comment: It doesn't help me! I knew all you said. I just don't know the specific method. But thank you, too